# What to do with exponent with different base in denominator?

Tags: logarithms

I‘m struggling right now with a equation. The equation is

$$\frac{2^{(5x)}}{7^{(x+2)}} = 10.$$

The solution should be $4.076$ but I don‘t know how to solve this equation.

I came to the conclusion that I can simplify the equation so it‘s $\frac{32^x}{7^{(x+2)}}$. My problem is that I don‘t know how I can get rid of the denominator.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial.  Note that $2^{5x}=32^x$ and $7^{x+2}=7^x49$

Comment: $a^x = b^{(\log_b a) \cdot x}$

Comment: $4.076$ is an approximate solution

Answer (score 4):

$$\dfrac{2^{5x}}{7^{x+2}}=10$$

$$\dfrac{32^x}{7^x49}=10$$

$$\left(\dfrac{32}7\right)^x=490$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me a lot and I‘m now able to solve the equation.

Answer (score 0):

You simplified $2^{5x}$ to $\left(2^5\right)^x=32^x$.

You can also simplify $7^{x+2}$ to $7^x\cdot7^2=49\cdot7^x$, using the exponent rule $a^{b+c}=a^b\cdot a^c$.

Thus, your equation simplifies to
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{32^x}{49\cdot7^x}&=10\\
\frac{1}{49}\cdot\frac{32^x}{7^x}&=10\\
\frac{32^x}{7^x}&=490\\
\left(\frac{32}{7}\right)^x&=490\\
\ln\left(\left(\frac{32}{7}\right)^x\right)&=\ln(490)\\
x\ln\left(\frac{32}{7}\right)&=\ln(490)\\
x&=\frac{\ln(490)}{\ln\left(\frac{32}{7}\right)}\\
x&\approx4.076
\end{align*}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{2^{(5x)}}{7^{(x+2)}}=10$$
$$\implies 2^{(5x)}=10\times7^{(x+2)}$$
Take logarithms of both sides and rearrange using the laws of logarithsms to find $x$, eg using $$\log a^b=b\log a$$.